# Default program for downloading torrents changed, can't download

Tags: default-programs, transmission

I was having no trouble downloading torrents with the default program in Ubuntu 14.10, Transmissions, but then I changed something, don't ask me what, and now it defaults to Videos, which of course will not download torrents.  How do I change it back?   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to change the default program. It's pretty simple.

First, right-click the .torrent file. It'll bring up a menu like this:

[image: this]

Select <kbd>Properties</kbd> (circled by orange here)

Next, select the **Open With** tab in the window that opens up:

[image: yours]

Your window may look slightly different than mine. If you don't see Transmission in the Suggested Applications section, just scroll down until you find it.

Then, click on <kbd>Set as default</kbd>.

You should now be able to open the .torrent file in Transmission!